# Migrate Windows Server 2008 configuration to Windows Server 2008

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, active-directory, dhcp-server, dcpromo

I've already taken a look at these questions:

- [Migrate Windows Server 2008 to another server](https://serverfault.com/questions/814701/migrate-windows-server-2008-to-another-server)
- [Migrate Windows Server 2008 to a new hard disk](https://serverfault.com/questions/143767/migrate-windows-server-2008-to-a-new-hard-disk)
- [Migrate Windows Server 2008 to a new hard disk 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/148710/migrate-windows-server-2008-to-a-new-hard-disk-2)

But I don't think they solve my situation.

I have a 32-bit installation of Server 2008 on an old Dell Dimension 3000. It's been slowly dying the past few years, and it's time to get rid of it. I also have a Dell PowerEdge 2950 with Server 2008 Standard 64-bit on it, which I want to use to replace the Dimension 3000.

The old server is acting as a DNS server, DHCP server and Domain Controller. How can I migrate this configuration to the PowerEdge? It looks like the full backup option won't work, since the source is 32-bit and I'd like to keep the PowerEdge on 64-bit. Is there a tool I can use for this or do I need to reconfigure manually?

Answer (score 2):

If it is only functioning as the AD, DNS, and DHCP server why don't you install and configure those services on the new server? Make the new server a DC. DC promo the old server. DC promo the new server. That will transfer the FSMO roles to the new server. DNS is AD integrated so that is addressed when you make the new server a DC. Then export the DHCP configuration from the old server. Disable the DHCP configuration on the old server. Import the DHCP configuration on the new server. Enable the DHCP configuration on the new server.

It requires you know how to install Windows Roles and Features, how to demote a DC, how to promote a DC, and how to manage DHCP configurations.

- Windows Roles and Features
- DCPromo: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732887(v=ws.11).aspx
- DHCP Management: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759224(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: I'll take a look through, but I'm more of a Linux person. I don't have much experience with Windows Server at all.

Comment: I think the core issue here is "Windows Server" and a lack of experience by the OP with this.  They will very likely need to know how to export the configs, and import on the new server, and enable roles/features, etc.  Even myself, after fiddling with Windows Servers for a couple years on and off, am not fully versed in this (I'm a linux guy heh, so is Zacharee), either.

Comment: Agreed which is why I after answering the question, I provided links to exhaustive instructions on how to perform each change.

Comment: @user5870571 except for Roles and Features.  Note they're also moving from 2k8 to 2k8R2,so unless the steps are identical (and I don't know because I only roll later Server versions out), they're going to get lost.

Comment: The steps are the same regardless. As to instructions, the only thing I didn't do is give screenshots. Server Manager opens automatically when you login and Roles and Features is right there in Server Manager.